# JavaScript: Looping through a prototype function's variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do something like this:

```
var MyFunction = function(Name) {
    var Handle = this;

    Handle.Name = Name;
}

var LoopThroughNames = function() {
    for(Name in MyFunction) { // This doesn't work.
        console.log(Name);
    }
}

var Handle1 = new MyFunction("Hello world!");
var Handle2 = new MyFunction("Test");

LoopThroughNames();
```

Sorry for lack of code tag, I am on my phone.

Comment: You're missing a lot of OO concepts there.. Class declaration x Class instantiate, looping properties x array, constructors...

Comment: I think the real intent of the O.P. is to loop through the instances of a Class.

Comment: GameAlchemist is a really helpful guy, I thank him dearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing the Class with the instance :
the Name property is added to the *instances* created with new.
The function MyFunction itself is not affected by those changes, so, yes, MyFunction has no own property .

Edit : following @JuanMendes 's idea, if you want to keep a hold on all
 created instances, you could store them within an array, and why not store
this array as a MyFunction property.
After a few name changes and such, i suggest :

```
function MyClass(name) {
    this.name = name;
    MyClass.instances.push(this);
}
MyClass.instances = [];

function printInstancesProperty( targetClass, propName) {
    for(var i=0; i< targetClass.instances.length; i++) { // This work.
        var instance =  targetClass.instances[i];
        console.log(instance[propName]);
    }
}

var Handle1 = new MyClass("Hello world!");
var Handle2 = new MyClass("Test");

printInstancesProperty(MyClass, 'name');
```

result is, expectedly :

```
"Hello world!"
"Test"
```

http://jsbin.com/yogahuze/2/edit?js,console

Comment: That's right, to look at it from another angle, the OP could change the code to track all the instances by doing `MyFunction.instances.push(this)`, assuming `instances` is initialized to an array or could also use `Name` the key of a map.

Comment: For the record, I knew they were classes, the same as C++ and PHP, but different types of class so I put "prototype function", cause this is also valid: MyFunction.prototype.Name = Name;

Comment: Beware that prototypal inheritance is very different from C++ inheritance. "prototype function" has no real meaning. All objects have prototypes, and function are objects, so they have also a prototype. I think you mean "constructor function" which is the js object closest to a class (== a function meant to be used with new). And since you defined Name only on the instances, not on the constructor prototype, no you don't have  MyFunction.prototype.Name = Name;  (! even if all instances do have the property set ! )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `LoopThroughNames()` implementation. You can't iterate over `MyFunction` because it's a function declaration, however you can iterate over the `Handle1` and `Handle2` objects that you've created.

```
var LoopThroughNames = function(instanceObject) {
    for(Name in instanceObject) {
        console.log(instanceObject[Name]);
    }
}

LoopThroughNames(Handle1); // "Hello world!"
LoopThroughNames(Handle2); // "Test"
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I'm looking for. =] thanks again the guy with 4 votes up answered me.

Answer (score -2):

```
var myFunction = function(name) {
    var handle = this;

    handle.name = name;
}

var loopThroughNames = function() {
    for (name in myFunction) { 
        console.log(name);
    }
}

var handle1 = new myFunction("Hello world!");
var handle2 = new myFunction("Test");

loopThroughNames();
```

it will work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you explain what in the code you have posted is an answer to the problem happening here, so that the user and future readers can learn from it?

Comment: I don't see anything different except you lowercased the first letter.